# Can I use a service to handle touch events?

Tags: android, service, android-service, multi-touch, android-gesture

I'm a new android developer. I want to use a service to handle touch events, here is code, only doTouch() work, I mean show "touched" only.If I want to show "DOWN","POINTER_DOWN","BEGIN", how do I do it? any help? Thanks in advance!
The logcat and the console shows nothing wrong.

```
public class MainService extends Service {

     private ViewService mViewService = null;
     @Override
     public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
     }

     @Override
     public void onCreate(){
         super.onCreate();
         startForeground(1, new Notification());
         mViewService = ViewService.getInstance(this);
         mViewService.addView(ViewService.TOUCH_VIEW);
         mViewService.getView(ViewService.TOUCH_VIEW).setOnTouchListener(new TouchListener());
     }

     //do touch event
     public void doTouch(){
         Toast.makeText(this, "touched", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

     }


class TouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener{

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE){
            MainService.this.doTouch();
            //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "TOUED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        /*else if(e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            MainService.this.doTouch();
        }*/
        /*if(e.getPointerCount() >= 3){
            MainService.this.doTouch();
        }*/
        switch (e.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "DOWN", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
            if(e.getPointerCount() >= 3){
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "POINTER_DOWN", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "BEGIN", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;
        default:
        break;
        }       
        return true;
     }
  }
 }
```

Comment: Could you be more specific?  Are you receiving any errors?  Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: How  can I chance single touch to multi touch in this service？

Comment: here is link[link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25661708/can-i-use-a-service-to-handle-multi-touch-events[link]

Comment: It appears you've solved the problem.  Please revise what the question was and post your solution as an answer so we can upvote, and also for the next person encountering that.

Comment: Actually,I don't solved the problem perfect. OnTouchListener use for single touch only.so I ask an new question. here is link[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25661708/can-i-use-a-service-to-handle-multi-touch-events)[link]

Answer (score 0):

```
Actually,I don't solved the problem perfect. OnTouchListener use for single touch only.
[so I ask an new question][1]
http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5694854

public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e){
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (e.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {      
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE:
        Log.d(TAG, "touched");
        MainService.this.doTouch();
        //work
        //break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        Log.d(TAG, "down");
        //work
        //break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
        Log.d(TAG, "pointer down");
        for(int i=0;i<e.getPointerCount();i++){
            downX[i] = e.getX(i);
            downY[i] = e.getY(i);
            //work
        }
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        int pointerCount=e.getPointerCount();
        Log.d(TAG, "move");
        Log.d(TAG, "c=" + pointerCount);
        if(pointerCount >= 2){
            //no work, pointerCount == 1 forever.
            //I think I should use onTouchEvent(),
            //but I dont know how to write on right way.
        }
    }
}
```