# Can I use a service to handle multi-touch events?

Tags: android, service, multi-touch

I want to write a multi-touch functionality in a service.How  can I change single-touch to multi-touch in this servic?

I found in this case e.getPointerCount() always == 1. Any idea?

Thanks at first!

```
public void onCreate(){
    super.onCreate();
    startForeground(1, new Notification());
    mViewService = ViewService.getInstance(this);
    mViewService.addView(ViewService.TOUCH_VIEW);
    mViewService.getView(ViewService.TOUCH_VIEW).setOnTouchListener(new TouchListener());
}


class TouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener{

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e){
       int pointerCount=e.getPointerCount();
       //question: why pointerCount always == 1？I wanna >=3.
       //how can I chance to multi-touch.
    }

   }
```

Comment: Why would you want to use a "touch" listener in a `Service`? A `Service` doesn't have a user interface.

Comment: because I want to write a multi-touch to Instead of home hey,back key and menu key,so I need use a multi-listener in a service.Of course ,it don't need a interface,except program menu.  these codes work,but for single touch only,need help!